# Magento 2.2.5 stop overlapping products description and reviews content

Tags: magento2, product-view-page

I have just finished setting up a new website over 1900 products. But i found an error on Firefox product description overlap with review tabs content, on chrome works fine.

Not sure how to get a fix. Either move review below description and remove the review tab. Its some settings in magento java scripts

[image]

Comment: Check for JavaScript error in console.

Comment: Thanks for your comments there is no error on the console

Comment: Is refreshing the page second time resolve the problem?

Comment: Yes. After refreshing 2nd time resolve it.